How to autoselect a result from a list
This is the output of my Segment Anything Model:

These are the segmentation results:
masks = [
    mask['segmentation']
    for mask
    in sorted(sam_result, key=lambda x: x['area'], reverse=True)
]

sv.plot_images_grid(
    images=masks,
    grid_size=(8, int(len(masks) / 8)),
    size=(16, 16)
)


The second segmentation in the list is what I want. My goal is to use that to erase out the background and just maintaing the car.
However, I want to do this automatically and while I can automate the process, the caveat is that I will have cars of different shapes. How do I automatically segment out the entirety of the car? How to go about this?

Merge the output of segment anything with grounding dino to get the car contour. and remove the other parts of the mask.

using salient object detection, then feed bounding box to SAM?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
